# Кириллица в Python

Tags: python, строки, кириллица

Есть ли в python аналог для `string.ascii_letters`, только для кириллицы?

```
>>> import string
>>> string.ascii_letters
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не думаю, что для кириллицы это есть.

Так что, вот:

```
cyrillic_lower_letters = 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'
cyrillic_letters = cyrillic_lower_letters + cyrillic_lower_letters.upper()
```

Comment: Ну да, я так примерно и сделал))

Comment: Вас устраивает правка вашего ответа? Дикое желание откатить

Comment: @Dmitry, да пусть будет, нормально :) Тут вопрос вкусовщины :)

Answer (score 2):

Зная, что код кириллических символов в таблице unicode идёт от 1040 до 1103, где сначала заглавные, а затем строчные, мы можем сделать так:

```
cyrillic_lower = [(lambda c: chr(c))(i) for i in range(1072, 1104)]
cyrillic_upper = [(lambda c: chr(c))(i) for i in range(1040, 1072)]
cyrillic_ansi = cyrillic_lower + cyrillic_upper
```

И получим следующий список:
`['а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я', 'А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'Й', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'О', 'П', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'У', 'Ф', 'Х', 'Ц', 'Ч', 'Ш', 'Щ', 'Ъ', 'Ы', 'Ь', 'Э', 'Ю', 'Я']`

Если нужно получить именно строку, то вот:

```
cyrillic_ansi_str = ''.join(cyrillic_ansi)
```

и соответствующий результат:
`'абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ'`

Comment: Желательно "магические" числа на ord заменить, типа: `range(ord('а'), ord('я')+1)`. Ну и буква `ё` потерялась.

Comment: @insolor А, точно, ё же ещё, надо поискать... А ответ свой я написал до того как комментарий увидел )

Answer (score 2):

Ну тогда и я свой вариант добавлю, если порядок следования букв не очень важен:

```py
cyrillic_letters = ''.join(map(chr, range(ord('А'), ord('я')+1))) + 'Ёё'
# 'АБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяЁё'
```

Будет работать в любой кодировке, где русские буквы идут в таблице подряд, начиная с `А` и заканчивая `я`. Правда, с `Ёё` отдельный прикол, но они обычно везде как-то отдельно лежат.